# How to randomly select models in django under specific conditions

Tags: django, sqlite, random

I've made a WebApp using django to organize a class room. I would like to generate random work groups of 2 students where each student speaks a different language. Every thing works but my results don't match that condition.

Here's my code:

```
from students.models import students
import random

#make a list of all students 
 a =list(students.objects.all())

#the select function
 def group (x,y):
    res = []
    for i in range(y):
        while len(res)<y:
             res = random.sample(x, k=y)
             while x[i].first_language == x[i-1].first_language:
                 group(x,y)
                 return None
     return res


#multiple call for the function
 for n in range(10):
     p = group(a,2)
     print(p)
```

If I call the function multiple times I get groups from students who speak the same language and this is wrong.

Comment: Interesting problem! But it strikes me as a bit more complex than described so far. Do you want to assign all students to a group? What to do with odd class sizes? What to do if there aren't sufficient students with different languages (e.g. 3 Hindi-speaking and 5 English-speaking)?

Comment: the idea mostly we make groups of two. we choose the number of students and the number of them in each group. i alaways give a divisible numbers and pre-calcualated results for testing. last product will handle all of this complexity. but now i stuck here. i think the problesm with this lise:

Comment: this condition is not accurate   while x[i].first_language == x[i-1].first_language:

Comment: I'm afraid I can't wrap my head around your code. There is probably a simpler, more readable and/or more feature-complete way to go about it, but for that you need to be clear about what you need.

Comment: today i have applied more conditions after the final results of the function, it is wprking 80% now.